# how to serve thumbnail version of default image with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thumbnails, carrierwave, default-value

My default image is working with carrierwave, except I can't get a thumb version of the default. `@profile.photo` and `@profile.photo.thumb` both return the same `default_profile.png`. How do I get this to work

Also, when I do upload a photo, `@profile.photo.thumb` does correctly return the resized version of the uploaded photo.

In **/assets/images**:

I have `default_profile.png` and `thumb_default_profile.png`, the latter is, of course, a scaled down version of the former. I also tried renaming the thumb file to `default_profile_thumb.png`

relevant portion of **profile_photo_uploader.rb:**

```
 def default_url
   "default_profile.png"
 end

 version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_fill => [60, 60]
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def default_url
 "default_profile.png"
end

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [60, 60]
  def default_url
    "thumb_default_profile.png"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nicer way todo:

```
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path([version_name, "default_profile.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
```